# Which approach is best for thread safe global storage for multithreaded environments in python (CPython)?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, thread-safety, gil

I have a requirement as below:

```py
global_storage = "some_global_storage_system"

def call_me():
    global_storage += 1
    if global_storage > 1000:
        with threading.Lock():
            global_storage = 0 # reset global storage
            # performing some action
```

Above code can be accessed by 5 threads at the same time

I have found a lots of approaches to do so but no where they are collected at one place and it's not mentioned which one of the following is the best and safest approach to implement something like `global_storage` in above program:

1. Using python `queues` library (as it is thread safe, but might be a memory issue) : Put an item in queue every time and check whenever the queue length becomes 1000, then make queue length 0 again.
2. Using a `dictionary` at global level (thread safe in Cpython): Make a dictionary, `global_dict["count"]=0`, and every time update `global_dict["count"]++` and then read `global_dict["count"]>1000`.
3. Using a `global` variable, using `global` keyword (least recommended one by community as it seems)
4. Using `redis`(Avoiding as it is an extra burden of network call): `redis.set()` at the start and `redis.get()` while getting the value
5. Using a `threading.local` object (it feels like the safest one), but then I may need to reduce the count for check to `200` to achieve same results.

Answer (score 1):

You need to realize that the operation `global_storage += 1` is probably *not* an atomic operation in almost any implementation of whatever "some_global_storage_system" you have in mind is. It certainly is not atomic if `global_storage` is an `int`, and you can't get much more basic than that. This means that this operation needs to be also serialized under a lock.

In the following code I have created at global scope a `threading.Lock` instance named `global_storage_lock` that all threads can access and use to serialize access to `global_storage`. My only (rhetorical) question to you concerns your comment labeled `#performing some action`, which you currently have while the lock is acquired. In general, you want to hold a lock for the shortest period possible. If you do not need to be updating `global_storage` during this action, then perform that action outside of this block where the lock will have been released.

```py
import threading

global_storage_lock = threading.Lock()
global_storage = "some_global_storage_system"

def call_me():
    with global_storage_lock:
        global_storage += 1
        if global_storage > 1000:
            global_storage = 0 # reset global storage
            # performing some action
```

Here is an example of how you could handle not requiring the lock to stay acquired when needing to perform an action after resetting `global_storage` to 0:

```py
import threading

global_storage_lock = threading.Lock()
global_storage = "some_global_storage_system"

def call_me():
    action_needed = False
    with global_storage_lock:
        global_storage += 1
        if global_storage > 1000:
            global_storage = 0 # reset global storage
            action_needed = True
    if action_needed:
        #performing some action
        ...
```

Comment: Got it. I have another doubt. Is it possible to implement something such that, only `one of the multiple threads` that can call `call_me` (Maybe a specific thread) can perform the action `#performing some action`?

Comment: Your last comment/question needs more details. It might be better for you to open a new question and describe more clearly how you would determine which thread gets the privilege of being able to run that action and under what condition.